# $f : I=[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Prove that the lower sum is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

Given a function $f : I=[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$f(x) = 1$, if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ 
$f(x) =0$, if $x\in I \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. 
Prove that for every partition $V$ of $I$ the following holds:
\begin{align}
\underline{S} (f,V) = 0
\end{align}
where $\underline{S}(f,V)$ is the lower sum.
If this is the case, I think I need to prove that there will always be an irrational number in every subinterval and this will imply that $\underline{S} (f,V) = 0$.
Is this the correct way to prove that $\underline{S} (f,V) = 0$?

Comment: Yes if you show that it follows lower sums are zero.

Comment: You mean $V$ is a **partition** of $I$, not a "distribution"...

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed what I meant @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: Are you having any trouble proving each subinterval contains an irrational? If so add to your question and there will likely be lots of answers.

Comment: @coffeemath I think I got it now